# bathroom synchronization and queue of threads

Tags: c++, semaphore

For homework we have been given the bathroom synchronization problem.  I have been struggling trying to figure out how to start.  What I would like to do when a person enter the restroom(personEnterRestrrom function), if they are female and no males are in the restroom they enter,if not they go into a queue for women waiting.  I want to do the same for men.  I tried to implement a queue that holds thread, but cannot get it to work. Then in personLeavesRestroom function.  When a person leaves if no one is left in the bathroom the other queue starts. Here is my code, I know I am far off, by I do need some guidance and am not very familiar with semaphores.

```
//declarations
pthread_mutex_t coutMutex;
int menInBath;
int womanInBath;
int menWaiting;
int womenWaiting;
queue<pthread_mutex_t>men;
queue<pthread_mutex_t>women;


 personEnterRestroom(int id, bool isFemale)
 {
   // LEAVE THESE STATEMENTS                                                 
   pthread_mutex_lock(&coutMutex);
  cout << "Enter: " << id << (isFemale ? " (female)" : " (male)") << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&coutMutex);

  // TODO: Complete this function                                           
 if(isFemale && menInBath<=0)
  {
     womanInBath++;
   }
 else if(isFemale && menInBath>0)
 {
  wait(coutMutex);
  women.push(coutMutex);
}
 else if(!isFemale && womanInBath<=0)
{
  menInBath++;
}
else
{
  wait(coutMutex);
  men.push(coutMutex);
}
```

}

```
   void
    personLeaveRestroom(int id, bool isFemale)  
    {
   // LEAVE THESE STATEMENTS                                                 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&coutMutex);
    cout << "Leave: " << id << (isFemale ? " (female)" : " (male)") << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&coutMutex);

  if(isFemale)
    womanInBath--;
  if(womanInBath==0)
    {
       while(!men.empty())
         {
           coutMutex=men.front();
           men.pop();
           signal(coutMutex);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: I think you want your queues to contain the ids and not the threads.

Comment: Actually you could make this simpler by just holding a boolean to indicate if the current people in the toilet are male or female and then just a counter. You need a synchronisation lock around the boolean and the counter so you don't need to hold a counter of men or women unless you want to hold a queue waiting, in which case you could use some form of queue and pop off when they are allowed to enter the restroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for FIFO mutex, this one could help you:

You gonna need:
**mutex** (`pthread_mutex_t mutex`),
**array of condition variables** (`std::vector<pthread_cond_t> cond`)
and **queue for storing thread IDs** (`std::queue<int> fifo`).

Let's say there is `N` threads with IDs `0` to `N-1`. Then `fifo_lock()` and `fifo_unlock()` could look like this (pseudocode):

```
fifo_lock()
    tid = ID of this thread;
    mutex_lock(mutex);
    fifo.push(tid); // puts this thread at the end of queue

    // make sure that first thread in queue owns the mutex:
    while (fifo.front() != tid)
        cond_wait(cond[tid], mutex);

    mutex_unlock(mutex);

fifo_unlock()
    mutex_lock(mutex);
    fifo.pop(); // removes this thread from queue

    // "wake up" first thread in queue:
    if (!fifo.empty())
        cond_signal(cond[fifo.front()]);

    mutex_unlock(mutex);
```